# OpenJPA native query how to use IN operator with a list

Tags: java, openjpa

I use OpenJPA 2.1 on WebSphere Application Server with a MySQL 5 DB.

I have a list of dates and want to use the IN operator to get only the entries from DB where the date in DB is also in the list.

```
List<Date> dates = new LinkedList<Date>();
dates.add(somedates);
```

My query looks like this:

```
  List<Object> list = em
    .createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT w.date FROM week_table w WHERE w.date IN ?1")
        .setParameter(1, dates).getResultList();
```

But I get an ArgumentException:
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.argumentexception the specified parameter of type is not a valid query parameter

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException:org.apache.openjpa.persistence.argumentexception the specified parameter of type "class java.util.LinkedList" is not a valid query parameter.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.setUnknown(DBDictionary.java:1426)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SQLStoreQuery$SQLExecutor.executeQuery(SQLStoreQuery.java:218)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1005)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:331)
```

So how can I pass a List or the List Values into my query?

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a JPQL (non native) query?

Comment: Would it work with a JPQL Query? Can I pass a List as parameter?

Comment: I assume so as JPQL supports this kind of thing. That is JPQL from JPA 2.0. see http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection